How do I configure Jenkins to use all available executors on a node, before using an empty node?
We are using the EC2 Fleet plugin to handle scaling Jenkins nodes on our build server. Each node has two executors (2 vCPUs on each VM).  We have also configured the plugin to always have 1 node free, to save on spin up times.
Jenkins decides to, more often than not, assign new jobs to the 'spare' node, rather than to another node that has a spare executor.  This causes the EC2 Fleet plugin to spin up another spare.  Often resulting in many nodes running, with only a single executor in use.
I guess what I'm looking for is the opposite of a load balancer, but i cannot find any guides/plugins that achieve this. Either that, or a way to configure the EC2 plugin to have a certain number of spare executors, rather than spare nodes.
Dropping the spare node config to 0 would probably resolve this issue, as jenkins would be forced to use all executors before requesting new nodes from EC2. However, this results in a few minutes of delay every time a new job comes along and there isnt a spare node ready to go.

You could size your instances for 1 executor.

That is one option.  But then we have wasted resources.  Unless we scale down the instance size to 1 vCPU.  Majority of the tasks performed are single threaded, and bottlenecked by the Salesforce platform were deploying to.

That's what I meant, if 2 vCPUs can handle 2 executors make 1 vCPU instance for 1 executor. If you have time you can run the same pipeline on different instance sizes and compare costs vs duration.
